# Calculating probability of an 11-card straight

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

My friends and I were playing a card game where you're dealt 11 cards (it was one of those "family games", so I'm not sure what we were playing. It was kind of like Canasta).

Anyway, on one of my deals my friend was dealt an 11-card straight, 3-K. Before dealing, I shuffled 7 times.

What are the odds of this happening? I never took probability courses, but it seems exceedingly rare from a layman's perspective.

I'm interested in the result, but I'm also very interested to see how the result is produced! I'm just starting to get back into math after a series of awful high school teachers.

Thank you!

Comment: We can of course try to criticize your shuffling ... but we'll make the assumption that the cards were dealt randomly, sure :)

Comment: The calculation is almost exactly the same as the calculation for a poker straight. There are four start-end choices (or three if aces don't go both ways) and four choices for each specific card's suit. There are then $4\cdot 4^{11} $ different straights possible. Taken out of the $\binom{52}{11}$ equally likely hands the probability then is $4^{12}/\binom{52}{11} \approx 0.000278$, so about one in four thousand deals this will happen

Comment: @Bram28 My shuffling is good enough, but that's something I was curious about as well :)  I think for this, assuming randomness is good enough

Comment: @Bram28 Also, straights aren't an objective in this game.  So I'm not sure now that would affect things if we assumed my shuffling was imperfect.

Comment: @JMoravitz Correction: there are only three 11-straights, not four.

Comment: @KieranE Well, it's an interesting problem for pure mathematics sake, but when you're dealing with real life scenarios like these, you'd be surprised (or maybe not, if you're a good critical thinker!) how often the assumptions we make in our mathematical models just don't hold in those situations,  Many people forget about that, are 'taken in' by the pure math, and draw some really inappropriate conclusions about the situation. Note that I am not saying that *you* are doing this :)

Comment: @parcly it is common in the US for ace to be considered as a 1 or as a 14 depending on the players needs at the time, so you have A,2,..., J on up to 4,5,..., A.  giving four straights not three.  I should have made that clear already in my initial comment with the "aces go both ways" phrase

Comment: @Bram28 That's true!  I was never stellar at math, but probability always seemed so interesting.  I'm surprised that the odds are as high as ~ 1-in-4800!  My initial reaction was that it would be much rarer than that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Right then. I don't play card games much, so I may not understand a few conventions.

Comment: @KieranE Yes, and showing that this event, even if we assume pure randomness, wasn't all *that* unlikely is what math *is* good for!  So between people generally being terrible at probability (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), and people not realizing that numerous events take place at any time (and thus, as Aristotle said: 'It is probable that improbable events happen'), we too quickly see meaning and patterns in completely random events. Or, in the case of someone getting a 11-card straight, that they are falsely being accused of cheating! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just a 3-K straight, the probability is
$$\frac{4^{11}}{\binom{52}{11}}=6.944×10^{-5}$$
The numerator arises because there are 4 possible suits for each card in the straight; the denominator is just the number of ways to deal an 11-card hand from the full deck.

If any 11-straight was allowed, the above probability would be multiplied by four because there are four such straights (A-J, 2-Q, 3-K, 4-A), leading to a probability of $2.778×10^{-4}$.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for the probability of any 11-straight, so $2.083×10^{-4}$ is the number!  Please excuse this silly question, but how would you turn that number to "one in ..." odds?

Comment: @KieranE Just take the reciprocal of the probability. My numbers turn into 1-in-14401 and 1-in-4800 respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and patience :).  That's much more common than I thought it'd be!

Answer (score -1):

Number of ways you can choose $11$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards is $\binom{52}{11}=\frac{52!}{11!41!}$. Number of ways those a set of $11$ cards contains $3$ K's, is (the number of ways of choosing $3$ K's from the $4$ K's)$\times$(the number of ways of choosing $8$ cards from the remaining $(52-4)$ cards)$=\binom{4}{3}\times\binom{48}{8}$. Thus the required probability is $$\frac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{8}}{\binom{52}{11}}$$

Comment: You interpreted "3-K" wrongly...

Comment: didnt it mean 3 kings?